# .vbs script wont run at login using AD

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I am trying to execute a printer script (.vbs) on logon for my company's users.

I am currently running a batch (.bat) file on startup through `Active Directory > Profile > Logon Script` which works as expected.

However, as as soon as I replace the .bat with a .vbs file it does not seem to run. The .vbs works when run manually.

Is the "Logon Script" property compatible with VBS scripting? I can't use GPO as I don't want to run it for the whole company, just a few users.

Answer (score 2):

> is AD not compatibe with .VB Scripting? i cant use GPO as i dont want to run it for the whole company just a few users

I'm not sure about your original question, but this is *exactly* what Group Policy is designed for. Create a GPO and either apply it to the relevant OU's or apply it higher up the tree and use Security Filtering to only include a Security Group containing the people who need this.

This will be neater and more manageable than manipulating the individual user objects.